# increment counter of calls in jquery

Tags: jquery, apply, increment, getjson

I will try to be as specific as I can.
I have the following code:

```js
$('table.list').before('<div id="tempinfo"></div>');
var pages = [0, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350, 400, 450, 500, 550, 600, 650, 700, 750, 800, 850, 900, 950, 1000, 1050, 1100, 1150, 1200, 1250, 1300, 1350, 1400, 1450, 1500, 1550, 1600, 1650, 1700, 1750, 1800, 1850, 1900, 1950, 2000, 2050, 2100, 2150, 2200, 2250, 2300, 2350, 2400, 2450, 2500, 2550, 2600, 2650, 2700, 2750, 2800, 2850, 2900, 2950];
var calls = [];

$.each(pages, function(i) {
  calls.push(
    $.getJSON('?site=list&offset=' + pages[i], (function(i) {
      return function(d) {
        var tbl = $('table.list');
        $(tbl).find('tr:not(:first)').each(function(y, tr) {
          data += $(tr).prop('outerHTML');
        });
        $('#tempinfo').append((i + 1) + ' / ' + pages.length + '<br>');
      };
    }(i)))
  );
});

$.when.apply($, calls).then(function() {
  $(data).each(function() {
    // do something
  });
});
```

First I create a div before the existent table where I want to put inside it a counter.
Second I have an array (pages) where each item is the offset of each of the pages of table I am retrieving data from.
Next I created another array (calls) where I will fill it with the steps to retrieve the data from the table.
Then I created a loop from the above array (pages).
As you can see I use the $.getJSON() for filling the calls array and collecting the data I want on the data variable, where I use it afterwards.
The $('#tempinfo') is NOT filled as expected and it produces the following list:

```
1 / 60
2 / 60
5 / 60
3 / 60
6 / 60
4 / 60
8 / 60
11 / 60
7 / 60
14 / 60
12 / 60
10 / 60
9 / 60
13 / 60
15 / 60
18 / 60
19 / 60
17 / 60
20 / 60
21 / 60
22 / 60
23 / 60
25 / 60
26 / 60
16 / 60
28 / 60
29 / 60
30 / 60
31 / 60
24 / 60
35 / 60
36 / 60
27 / 60
33 / 60
32 / 60
38 / 60
39 / 60
40 / 60
43 / 60
41 / 60
34 / 60
46 / 60
44 / 60
37 / 60
47 / 60
42 / 60
49 / 60
50 / 60
51 / 60
52 / 60
45 / 60
54 / 60
55 / 60
56 / 60
58 / 60
59 / 60
48 / 60
53 / 60
57 / 60
60 / 60
```

Even if I have look around I didn't manage to find sth that I can solve this problem.
Is there a solution for this problem?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? You've descrived what is happening, but not what you **expect*** to happen. If the issue is that the responses are not coming back in the order you sent them, this is expected behaviour due to the async nature of the calls being made. You will need to `sort()` data within `$.data()`. Better still - ***do not make AJAX calls in a loop***. You are DDOSing your own server. Change the endpoint to return all data from a single call.

Comment: The problem is the counter is not sorted. I have already sorted the data afterwards.
Unfortunaterly, I cannot avoid such a process by making AJAX calls in a loop.
The list is already splitted in groups of 50 records and I cannot change this.
Anyway, I managed to add a cnt variable that increments after each AJAX call and the problem is solved. Thanks.